# Is there "text building block" page for math.se?

Tags: discussion

Every now and again, specific comments are needed to indicate to the user that their question is either badly worded or they need to provide more information or they need to provide more of their on work. I have seen something like the following:

> Welcome to Math.se! Please provide some of your own work to indicate how much you know and at what level people answering the question should provide an answer.

Depending on what the situation is, there is some variation but the gist remains that. Over at [Tex.se](http://tex.se) they have something called a [text building block](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) post where there is a large amount of pre-made comments that users can copy and paste onto posts. So, my first question is **do we have something like this?** and my second question is, if we don't, **can we get something like this?**

The main reason behind this would be that we can have a variety of uniform comments that we can use for new users or we can use them to explain a close vote. Furthermore, we can also have responses for questions that have already been answered through canonical answers/questions. There are also some links that people could find useful e.g. oeis.org that we can have as premade comments. There are numerous possibilities and we can draw some inspiration from text building block page.

Comment: I wonder if "Does X exist?" should be closed as a duplicate of "X"... why not just answer the question saying "Yes, here it is!"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In view of [Douglas Stones' comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/is-there-text-building-block-page-for-math-se?noredirect=1#comment40517_10743): the answer to the question you asked in the title is

## [Yes we do.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates)

Comment: I suppose I better +1 this (: